# Adding parameter in link causes network error (Android 4.0.3+PhoneGap)

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

When trying to navigate from index.html page to purchase.html, this "A Network error occurred" would appear if I add a parameter to the link

```
<a href="purchase.html?id=2">.
```

Removing the "?id=2" then the link works.

This is the detailed error msg:
04-08 21:09:23.850: D/Cordova(967): DroidGap: GapViewClient.onReceivedError: Error code=-1 Description=A network error occurred. URL=file:///android_asset/www/purchase.html?id=2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems to be a major issue of Android. http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17535

Comment: Yes, please star the issue. In the mean time use localStorage to pass parameters between pages.

Comment: That is actually a more elegant solution!